# update user info permission in Django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have set permission to the update method to allow only the Admin user to update the user info but for some reasons when I logged in as normal user I can also update the user info. What can I do to avoid that? other methods work just fine.

```
class CustomUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CustomUserSerializer
    parser_classes = [JSONParser]

    permission_classes_by_action = {
        'create': [IsAdminUser], 'list': [IsAdminUser], 'retrieve': [IsAuthenticated],
        'update': [IsAdminUser], <--already set here
        'destroy': [IsAdminUser,]
    }

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CustomUserViewSet, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # some other methods

    def get_permissions(self):
        try:
            # return permission_classes depending on `action`
            return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes_by_action[self.action]]
        except KeyError:
            # action is not set return default permission_classes
            return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
```

Comment: Which http method is using to update the values? HTTP PUT or HTTP PATCH?

Comment: it's patch method

Comment: if i use put method it will says `password field is required`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DRF ViewSets, the *HTTP PATCH* method is mapped with action name ***`partial_update`***. So you have to update the **`permission_classes_by_action`** attribute as

```
permission_classes_by_action = {
    'create': [IsAdminUser],
    'list': [IsAdminUser],
    'retrieve': [IsAuthenticated],
    'update': [IsAdminUser],

    'partial_update': [IsAdminUser],

    'destroy': [IsAdminUser, ]
}
```

Comment: I have tried it already. With `patial_update` i got 2 methods `put` and `patch`. I still can update the user info the patch and if i use put it will says `password field is require`

Comment: remove the `try...except` clause and see whats happening

Comment: when i wrote what u told and removed try and exept and kept  only the first return statement and it says `return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes_by_action[self.action]]
KeyError: None`

Comment: it's working now thanks! I never noticed that I have to have both `update` and `partial_update`. Thanks you.